# How to open private and normal window together in selenium webdriver with Java?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

My use case is to test Chat application. Verify user A sends message from Normal window and verify that user B received it successfully in incognito mode.

If open same thing in new tab or or window then same login will apply in new tab or window. So I want it to open in incognito mode.

Answer (score 0):

if you need to open a new chrome driver in incognito mode you can do it like this in java:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
capabilities.setCapability("chrome.switches", Arrays.asList("--incognito"));
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

Comment: Thanks @gazzo. But how can use these 2 browsers together. Like Can I switch the browser with same driver as per script?

Comment: I never tried, but I suppose you can instantiate two different drivers (one with incognito option) in the same test case and use them both to achieve what you want

Answer (score 0):

to open new tab, you could do this  :

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.open()");
```

remember to switch to it once it's open :

```
ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());
driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1));
```

and now you have the access to new tab.

**Update 1 :**

there is this shortcut : `CTRL + N`

```
WebElement body = driver.findElement(By.tagName("body"));
body.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL + "n");
```

Comment: Hi @cruisepandey, I want to open new window not Tab, as mentioned in the question